# Android id in webview url

Tags: android, android-webview, app-id

I have an android application with webview and I want to send the unique device ID to a PHP file. How can I add the android_id (or device id,app id) on the webview url?

Something like this:

```
webview launchUrl = "https://www.exampledomain.com/myphp.php?androidid=ANDROID_ID";

ANDROID_ID= xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Your question is ambigous, are you want add android id to php file or java file ? And what is android id ? attribute id from xml, or value of IP from device or what ? If in php android id just added with global $_GET['andoidid'] = $value;

Comment: ANDROID_ID= xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
webview launchUrl = "https://www.exampledomain.com/myphp.php?androidid="+ANDROID_ID;
concat the ANDROID_ID with launchUrl

Comment: I need the device id(UUID) to send via GET in webview becouse i need to register in PHP every device to send the distinct notification based on every device id. For example: invoice notification, service activated deactivated etc.Simply i need to know in php what is the id of each device to target them and send notification.

Comment: I do it like Sanil said but i get this error -  cannot assign a value to final variable 'ANDROID_ID'

Answer (score 0):

I use for my android app Cordova + Webview + Onesignal. I have this code now:

```
private static String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
private static final String PREFS_GT_PLAYER_ID = "GT_PLAYER_ID";

public synchronized static String id(Context context) {
    if (uniqueID == null) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_GT_PLAYER_ID, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        uniqueID = sharedPrefs.getString(PREFS_GT_PLAYER_ID, null);
        if (uniqueID == null) {
            uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
            editor.putString(PREFS_GT_PLAYER_ID, uniqueID);
            editor.commit();
        }
    }
    return uniqueID;
}



private void setStartUrl(String src) {

    Pattern schemeRegex = Pattern.compile("^[a-z-]+://");
    Matcher matcher = schemeRegex.matcher(src);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        launchUrl = src;
    } else {
        if (src.charAt(0) == '/') {
            src = src.substring(1);
        }
        launchUrl = "https://www.exampledomain.com/myphp.php?androidid=" + uniqueID;

    }
}
```

The uniqueID is random generated but i want to generate the player_id from onesignal.
[This is a print screen from my onesignal account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLLl0.jpg)